# Xpath, Scrapy, printing contents from a div class, using a id?

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Sample of the code below:

```
<div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content="" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="fmh1ij-accordion-label" aria-hidden="true" id="fmh1ij-accordion">

Number of Seats:    Seventeen (17) certified seats for take-off &amp; landing - including jump seat
<br>

Forward Cabin:  Four (4) place executive club seats with pull-out tables
<br>
Mid Cabin:  Four (4) place conference group opposite three (3) place 16G divan
<br>
Aft Cabin:  Two (2) place executive club seats opposite three (3) place 16G divan
<br>
Lavatory Location(s):   Forward crew lavatory and fully enclosed aft lavatory
<br>
```

I need to extract the contents below the 'div class=accordion-content'. Is there any way to do that using the id? 'id="fmh1ij-accordion"?

What I need extracted:

"Number of seats: Seventeen (17), etc.
Forward Cabin: Four (4), etc..."

I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
response.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'fmh1ij-accordion')]//text()").extract()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we are dealing with an id tag there is no need to use `contains`, you should search the XPath for the element that matches the id tag you are looking for:

```
response.xpath("//div[@id='fmh1ij-accordion']//text()").extract()
```

Try the snippet above and please let me know if it worked.

## EDIT

After checking the source URL it seems that id tag is dynamically generated. In that case I would suggest to select the element by class or using a different XPath.
Two suggestions for you:

```
response.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Interior")]/following-sibling::div//text()').extract()


response.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"accordion-item") and contains(a/text(), "Interior")]/div//text()').extract()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code above raises the following error: "ValueError: XPath error: Invalid predicate in //div[@id='fmh1ij-accordion')]//text()"

Comment: There's an orphaned ) bracket contained in the square brackets, just after: @id='fmh1ij-accordion'

Comment: @SandstormNick Good eye Nick! I removed the bracket and don't get an error anymore, but the output is an empty list. Code I used for reference: "response.xpath("//div[@id='fmh1ij-accordion']//text()").extract()"

Comment: @SandstormNick Nice catch, fixing it now, thank you!

Comment: @Arty can you provide the link? If not, can you check if the HTML your spider is getting is the same your browser? There are a few cases where this is an issue, like when content is dinamically loaded by javascript for example, or the page tries to protect against crawlers.

Comment: @Arty you can use `view(response)` in shell to render the page in the browser, or you can check `response.body` or `response.text` for the code. In this particular case it seems the id tags are generated dynamically, for me it's `el3duw-accordion`. Which probably means you have a different id for browser and shell. I suggest you get the element by class.

Comment: @Arty Edited my answer, please take a look if it solves your issue.

Comment: Oh! Yeah I see what you mean. I didn't know that the id tags could change like that. Originally, the reason I wanted to use ID tags was because div class="accordion-content" has 4 results within the HTML and I noticed that each one of those had a unique ID tag, which is why I thought I could use it. Unfortunately, now I know I can't though. I need the contents from each div class="accordion-content" separated but if I use the following code everything gets printed together in a list. I'll keep trying to figure this out!

Comment: You can select all the divs without the text, run then through a loop and extract the text inside the loop. Just an idea :)

Comment: @renatodvc It works! I can change "Interior" to other names from which I need to extract data to get the results separated. Thank you for your help!